# How to expand first two categorized colons and colapse the third one in Lotus view?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have a view in Lotus Notes application.
This view has first three columns defined as categorized (with a twistie).
I have "Collapse all when database is first opened" in View properties - Info tab.
I'd like to set first and second column expanded and the third one collapsed every time when user will open this view.
This is how this view should look like:
[View example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMc4t.jpg)
What should I put into PostOpen?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really possible.

You could walk through view with NotesViewNavigator but there is no method to expand or collapse categories.

There are @ commands for expanding and collapsing categories but with formula language it's not really possible to walk through view with a controlled end.

I don't see a way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks. 
Does your answer also apply to LotusScript?

Comment: Yes, NotesViewNavigator is a class in LotusScript.